# What makes a set into a "space"?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Does a space require more than one dimension? For instance $\Bbb R$ is not a space but $\Bbb R^2$ is?

Comment: A space is typically a set with more properties, and so will have an adjective such as "vector space", "topological space", or "Hilbert space" along with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A space often, but not exclusively, refers to a topological space; that is, a set with a distinguished collection of open subsets. Under this lens, $\mathbb{R}$ is a space in many ways, but at least in the Euclidean topology.

Dimension is not a restriction to being a space.

Comment: So there is no such thing as just a "space", it must fall into one of the different types of spaces e.g. Vector, Hilbert, Topolgoical?

Comment: @Charlie, that’s right. Calling something a “space,” it should be clear from the context what that word should mean.